# Extrapolation command in Octave

Tags: octave, gnu

I want to do interpolation and extrapolation. I can interpolate by using `interp2` command. But, this command didn't perform extrapolation. Is there any built-in function for extrapolation in octave? I have given an example in detail.

```matlab
a= [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]; 
b= [ 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011]; 
c= [ -0.88 -8.87 -0.86 -0.82 -0.77 -0.71 -0.66 -0.62 -0.57 -0.54 -0.50 -0.47 -0.44 -0.42 -0.39 -0.377 -0.36 -0.89 -0.88 -0.85 -0.81 -0.76 -0.71 -0.66 -0.61 -0.57 -0.53 -0.50 -0.47 -0.44 -0.42 -0.39  -0.37 -0.36]; 
cc = repmat(c,34,1); 

ci= interp2(a, b, cc, 1.5, 0.0015) % Interpolation at some point 

ai= [ 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 9 9.5 10 10.5 11 11.5 12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5 15 15.5 16 16.5 17 17.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 9 9.5 10 10.5 11 11.5 12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5 15 15.5 16 16.5 17 17.5]; 
bi= [ 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.001 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0015 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.0017 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011 0.011]; 
cim= interp2(a, b, cc, ai, bi) % Interpolation matrix 

ce= interp2(a, b, cc, 18, 0.2)  % Extrapolation at some point 

ae= 4* [ 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 9 9.5 10 10.5 11 11.5 12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5 15 15.5 16 16.5 17 17.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5 5.5 6 6.5 7 7.5 8 8.5 9 9.5 10 10.5 11 11.5 12 12.5 13 13.5 14 14.5 15 15.5 16 16.5 17 17.5]; 
be= [ 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.101 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1015 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.1017 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111 0.111]; 
cem= interp2(a, b, cc, ae, be)  % Extrapolation matrix
```

How can I find `ce` and `cem` in this case?  Here, it gives "NA". How should I extrapolate to find `ce` and `cem`? This code works in Octave only.

Thanks in advance

Sarah

Comment: I'm unsure what you're trying to do. But you can start by simplifying your example using things such as `a = 1:17`, `b = repmat (0.001, [1 17])` and `ai = 1:0.5:17.5`

Comment: Thanks for replying Carandraug! Ok, I will simplified my code.  In my case a, b and c are given. For interpolation, my task is to add values to “a” and “b” like adding 1.5 between 1 and 2 and so on. Similarly for “b” add 0.0015 between 0.001 and 0.011 and so on. I have to add same number of points for a and b, and thus c values will be automatically generated.

Answer (score 0):

The most similar command for data outside convex hull in octave to *scatteredInterpolant* of Matlab is griddata. For more information about griddata, griddata3 and griddatan read [octave documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Interpolation-on-Scattered-Data.html).